# How do I calculate the next iteration for Conway's Game of Life in 3D?

Tags: python, dictionary, conways-game-of-life

I am writing a script which generates a dictionary with locations of cubes in 3D space, calculates the neighbors for each cube and then calculates the new iteration based on the rules in [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life). My grid is a dictionary of even-numbered tuples, like so:

```py
grid = {(0, 0, 0): True, (0, 0, 2): True, (2, 0, 0): True, (2, 0, 2): True, (0, 2, 0): True, (0, 2, 2): True, (2, 2, 0): True, (2, 2, 2): True}
```

`True` or `False` denotes whether a cell is `alive` or `dead`.

To calculate the Moore neighbours for each cube, I wrote the following function:

```py
# Calculates the neighbors of a cell
def get_neighbors(grid, x,y,z):
    count = 0
    for pos in (
        # List out all possible neighbours of cell
        (x-2,y-2,z-2),
        (x-2,y-2,z),
        (x-2,y-2,z+2),
        (x-2,y,z-2),
        (x-2,y,z),
        (x-2,y,z+2),
        (x-2,y+2,z-2),
        (x-2,y+2,z),
        (x-2,y+2,z+2),
        (x,y-2,z-2),
        (x,y-2,z),
        (x,y-2,z+2),
        (x,y,z-2),
        (x,y,z+2),
        (x,y+2,z-2),
        (x,y+2,z),
        (x,y+2,z+2),
        (x+2,y-2,z-2),
        (x+2,y-2,z),
        (x+2,y-2,z+2),
        (x+2,y,z-2),
        (x+2,y,z),
        (x+2,y,z+2),
        (x+2,y+2,z-2),
        (x+2,y+2,z),
        (x+2,y+2,z+2)):
        if pos in grid:
            # If the neighbour is alive, add 1 to the count
            if grid[pos] == True:
                count += 1
    return count

# Checks if a cell is alive
def is_alive(grid, x,y,z):
    if (x,y,z) in grid:
        if grid[(x,y,z)] == True:
            return True
    return False
```

This outputs the number of neighbours correctly and returns whether a given tuple has `True` or `False`. To calculate the next iteration and include the rules for Game of Life, I wrote:

```py
# Calculates the next iteration of the game
def next_iteration(grid):
    new_grid = {}
    length = len(grid)
    # Iterate through the grid with range step size of 2, 
    # since we only have even numbers in the tuples.
    for x in range(0,length, 2):
        for y in range(0,length, 2):
            for z in range(0,length, 2):
                # Get the number of neighbors of the cell
                neighbors = get_neighbors(grid, x,y,z)
                if is_alive(grid, x,y,z):
                    # If the cell is alive, check if it should die
                    if neighbors < 2:
                        new_grid[(x,y,z)] = False
                    elif neighbors > 3:
                        new_grid[(x,y,z)] = False
                    else:
                        new_grid[(x,y,z)] = True
                else:
                    # If the cell is dead, check if it should be alive
                    if neighbors == 3:
                        new_grid[(x,y,z)] = True
                    else:
                        new_grid[(x,y,z)] = False
    return new_grid
```

However, if I generate a `2x2x2` grid and try to calculate iterations three times, I get [this](https://pastebin.com/R7bVkuZ7) (attaching only a part of the output) where **everything** is `False`. That doesn't seem right.

What is my code doing wrong? Am I not calculating neighbours correctly, or are the rules not being  checked properly?

How do I implement this 3D Game of Life correctly?

My full script is [here](https://gist.github.com/thedivtagguy/d1463037af11ad1aa0e4bb4964daf4a1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code actually sometimes produces a few `True` values - depending on the initial configuration. Almost all values will be `False` though, since at every iteration you are expanding the grid including a lot of cells that are far away from any alive cell, so their value must be `False`. This goes as follows:

- You start with a grid of 8 cells, with coordinates given by 0 or 2.
- After the first iteration you obtain a grid with 4**3 = 64 cells with coordinates 0, 2, 4, and 6. Only cells with coordinates 0, 2, and 4 can be alive.
- After 2 iterations the grid consists of cells with coordinates given by all even numbers between 0 and 63. Only cells with coordinates 0, 2, 4, and 6 can be possibly alive. There are 64 such cells in a grid consisting of 32**3 = 32768 cells.
- After 3 iterations the grid will have 16384**3 = 4398046511104 cells and the code will crash due to lack of memory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How were you able to find the number of True values? Is there anyway to optimize this for memory by not having so many empty cells? Should I be deleting cells that are too far away or something of the sort?

Comment: @Aman To get the number of `True` values you can just take the sum of  all values of the `grid` dictionary. As for the number of cells, there is no need to create so many empty cells. Even assuming that you want your grid to grow with each iteration, a grid of the size nxnxn should become (n+2)x(n+2)x(n+2) - since only cells bordering already existing cells can possibly become alive. You code is instead creating a grid of the size mxmxm where m = (n**3)//2.